# Multiply Power of Double with nullable Decimal

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
Double factor = 0.7;

Decimal? value = getValue(); 

Decimal? = - Math.Pow(factor, 3) * value;
```

And I get the error:

```
Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal?'
```

I am using Double as factor because Math.Pow only supports Double.

What would be the best option to do this multiplication?

The thing I cannot change is that `value` is a nullable `Decimal`, e.g., `Decimal?`

Comment: You're missing a variable name in the third line.

Comment: Check if the `value` is  null before the `Math.Pow` call, and if it is null, skip the call?

Comment: You can cast Math.Pow a doble to anything or a decimal to a double.  I would use : Math.Pow(factor, 3) * (double)value

Comment: How do we evaluate "best" when you ask for the "best option" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options

```
Decimal? someValue = value.HasValue ? -(decimal)Math.Pow(factor, 3) * value.Value : null;
```

or

```
Decimal? someValue = value.HasValue ? (decimal?)(-Math.Pow(factor, 3) * (double)value.Value) : null
```

Be aware of the [ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) for these floading point types. The first decimal cast in either case could be `decimal` or `decimal?`. It's a matter of taste I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the explicit casting. This code will give you a decimal or a null value:

```
Double factor = 0.7;

Decimal? value = getValue(); 
Decimal? d = (decimal?)(-Math.Pow(factor, 3)) * value;
```